# Does anyone know how to fetch WASDE (World Agricultural supply and demand estimates) report fundamental data by using API in Python or R?

Tags: python, r, quantitative-finance

https://usda.library.cornell.edu/apidoc/index.html The web site has provided the API doc. Can somebody tell me the required steps to fetch the data either in **R** or Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you can do it in R.

First, create variables containing the email address and password you created when you signed up:

```
my_email    <- "Niket_Chauhan@somewhere.com"
my_password <- "Passw0rd!"
```

You are going to need to send these inside a json string as a POST request to get an authorization code to use the service. We'll create the json now:

```
my_json <- paste0('{"auth": {"email":"', my_email,'","password":"', my_password, '"}}')
```

Now we'll request an authorization token using `httr::POST`:

```
library(httr)

auth <- POST("https://usda.library.cornell.edu/user_token",
             body = my_json, encode = "raw",
             add_headers(`Content-Type` = "application/json"))
```

If everything went well, `auth` now contains our authorization token. We will use this token inside an 'Authorization' header for every subsequent request to the server:

```
token <- add_headers("Authorization" = paste("Bearer", content(auth, "parsed")$jwt))
```

So now we can just send http requests to the API using `GET` and `POST`. For most of these we can just use the url we want, and ensure we have included our header.

```
res <- GET("https://usda.library.cornell.edu/api/v1/agency/findAll", token)
```

Here, `res` is an http response object, so we'll extract its contents as text to get our json string:

```r
cat(content(res, "text"))
#> [{"id":"waob_agency","title":["World Agricultural Outlook Board"],
#> "acronym":["WAOB"],"contact_email":["oce@oce.usda.gov"],"contact_phone":
#> ["202-720-5447"],"location_city":["Washington"],"location_state":
#> ["DC"],"homepage_url":["http://www.usda.gov/oce/commodity/"]},
#> {"id":"ers_agency","title":["Economic Research Service"],"acronym":
#> ["ERS"],"contact_email":["ers@ers.usda.gov"],"contact_phone":
#> ["202-694-5139"],"location_city":["Washington"],"location_state":
#> ["DC"],"homepage_url":["http://www.ers.usda.gov/"]},
#> {"id":"nass_agency","title":["National Agricultural Statistics Service"],
#> "acronym":["NASS"],"contact_email":["nass@nass.usda.gov"],
#> "contact_phone":["800-727-9540"],"location_city":["Washington"],
#> "location_state":["DC"],"homepage_url":["http://www.nass.usda.gov/"]},
#> {"id":"fas_agency","title":["Foreign Agricultural Service"],"acronym":
#> ["FAS"],"contact_email":["fas@fas.usda.gov"],"location_city":
#> ["Washington"],"location_state":["DC"],"homepage_url":
#> ["http://www.fas.usda.gov/"]},{"id":"ams_agency","title":
#> ["Agricultural Marketing Service"],"acronym":["AMS"],"contact_email":
#> ["ams@ams.usda.gov"],"contact_phone":["202-720-8998"],"location_city":
#> ["Washington"],"location_state":["DC"],"homepage_url":
#> ["http://www.ams.usda.gov/"]}]
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. It really helped a lot.

Comment: Hi @Allan Cameron! I'm trying to get a grasp of your solution to create a code script that pulls the latest WASDE spreadsheet (e.g September's spreadsheet in https://www.usda.gov/oce/commodity/wasde). Is there a way to do this?

Comment: @Tanga94 can't you just do `download.file("https://www.usda.gov/oce/commodity/wasde/wasde0821.xls", "myfile.xls")` if you want to download the spreadsheet?

Comment: Hi @AllanCameron, I could do that but I was hoping to create a script that automatically scrapes data from the latest release of the WASDE (as opposed to always manually downloading the spreadsheet by specifying the link every month)

Comment: @Tanga94 you can scrape data from the spreadsheet by downloading it and using a package that reads spreadsheets, like "readxl". You can easily download the data, read it into R, process it however you like, then delete the file at the end of your script, so the whole thing is automated.